# SAP ABAP CDS View / DCL check authorization

Tags: abap, sap-erp, cds

I have a CDS view and would like to apply authorization checks.

#### CDS View `ZCDS_VIEW`

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZCDS_VIEW'
@VDM.viewType: #BASIC
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
define view ZCDS_VIEW
  as select distinct from vbak
    inner join            vbap              on vbap.vbeln = vbak.vbeln // At least 1 item
    [...]
{
  key vbak.vbeln,
      vbak.ktext,       
      [...]
}
where
    [...].
```

My concern is that the way to control authorizations requires checks in different tables and not just an authorization check on a field in the CDS view.
Indeed, I must:

1. Check the authorizations on the profit center of a specific table ZT1
2. Make a join of the entries of the ZT1 table with a ZT2 table which gives me the authorized divisions
3. Filter the results of my CDS view with the authorized divisions.

To do that I did like this:

#### Create CDS `ZCDS_AUTH_PLANT`

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZCDS_AUTH_PLANT'
@VDM.viewType: #BASIC
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
define view ZCDS_AUTH_PLANT
  as select distinct from zt1
    inner join            zt2 on zt2.bu = zt1.bu
{
  zt1.prctr  as profit_center,
  zt2.bukrs  as company_code,
  zT2.werks as plant_code
};
```

#### Create DCL `ZDCL_AUTH_PLANT`

```
@MappingRole: true
define role ZDCL_AUTH_PLANT {
  grant
    select
      on
        ZCDS_AUTH_PLANT
          where
            ( profit_center ) = aspect pfcg_auth( XXX, PRCTR );
}
```

#### Update CDS `ZCDS_VIEW`

Addition of the join condition on `ZCDSC4_AUTH_PLANT` to have authorized divisions.

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZCDS_VIEW'
@VDM.viewType: #BASIC
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
define view ZCDS_VIEW
  as select distinct from vbak
    inner join            ZCDSC4_AUTH_PLANT on ZCDSC4_AUTH_PLANT.plant_code = vbap.werks // At least 1 item matching division
    [...]
{
  key vbak.vbeln,
      vbak.ktext,       
      [...]
}
where
    [...].
```

I wanted to know:

- Is this a good practice?
- Do you see a more relevant alternative?
- Should we do everything in the DCL?

Comment: here you are asking about ABAP CDS on HANA DB or about native HANA CDS? this makes a great difference. In your question I see all the views are defined in ABAP CDS

Comment: Yeah my bad i will update title i speak about ABAP CDS

Comment: I'd rather define the DCL directly on the ZCDS_VIEW instead of defining a technical entity in the data model. Note that DCLs can also contain paths, so if your ZCDS_VIEW had an association to _plant_, one could do `( plant.profit_center ) = aspect pfcg_auth( ... )` in the DCL. The main advantage would be better debug tooling and better coupling between the DCL and what it actually protects.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good practice?

The DCL is the standard way to implement authorization checks for ABAP CDS views, so yes, using it is a good practice.

This is included in the official documentation here [Access Control for CDS Entities](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f2e545608079437ab165c105649b89db/7.5.21/en-US/7072ee4d6bf41014b5040bee4e204223.html) and here [Creating DCL Sources](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f2e545608079437ab165c105649b89db/7.5.21/en-US/707332186bf41014b5040bee4e204223.html)

> Do you see a more relevant alternative?

Is using a DCL file not working for your requirements? If it is working, you are already using the correct way to implement auth checks, so no alternative solution is needed

> Should we do everything in the DCL?

If everything means the complete authorization checks, then yes.
You can also have more complex logic in the DCL of course than only checking for the PCFG object (for instance for GDPR limitations), but it doesn't seem to apply to your scenario